# Is it possible to post multiple xml documents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

This works:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "text/xml",
     processData: false,
     data: xmlDoc1
 });
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "text/xml",
     processData: false,
     data: [ xmlDoc1, xmlDoc2 ]
 });
```

Comment: You can concatenate the two documents yourself. That would mean that your server would be prepared to parse two XML documents out of a single source file, which is not impossible but is something a lot of XML parsers won't do.

Comment: @Pointy I'm using c# on the server side. do you know of a xml parser that has this functionality?

Comment: Well with the approach in the answer below, you'd get the two documents as independent parameters, so you could more easily (maybe) extract them and parse them individually. The issue is that XML is a *document* syntax, and two documents next to each other do not comprise a "document".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass an object containing the both files:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     data: {
         xml1: xmlDoc1,
         xml2: xmlDoc2 
     }
 });
```

To clarify, as stated by @Pointy in the comments, both docs need to be strings either way.

Comment: You can't do this. You should remove your answer because it may confuse someone.

Comment: Sure you can @T.Holland

Comment: @T.Holland What do you mean? You can certainly do this. *edit* well, you can if those "xmlDoc" things are strings. If they're not, then you're going to need to make them strings first no matter what.

Comment: @Pointy the body of the request looks like this [object Object] when you send it like data: {xml1: xmlDoc1 }

Comment: You're posting with jQuery, right? jQuery will convert the "data" property into a query string. If those document references are references to parsed DOM nodes, you need to convert those to strings first.

Comment: Try to convert it to a string first with `var xmlString1 = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc1);` and post the string. If that doesn't work directly, see this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/How_to_create_a_DOM_tree